# route.afterModel hook not being hit

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

The afterModel hook is not being hit when you attempt to transitionTo from a parent route to the same route.

I expected the afterModel hook to always fire.

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/03825ecbcf0ae48f940db926594a58c9?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

**Edit:**
It's kind of hard to understand unless you are can look at the twiddle but here's the code

```
// Controller/application.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  actions: {
    goTo() {
        this.transitionToRoute('food');
    }
  }
});

// templates/application.hbs
<button onclick={{action 'goTo'}}>Food Options</button>
<br>
{{outlet}}

//router.js
const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'none',
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('food', function() {
    this.route('options');
    this.route('fruits');
    this.route('veggies');
  });
});

//routes/food.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {},
  afterModel() {
    this.transitionTo('food.options');
  }
});
```

Clicking the food options button the first time correctly calls the afterModel in food route.  Clicking it the second time does not hit the afterModel.

Comment: Can you paste your transitionTo part of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [AlexSpeller Diagonal](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal) to see what route structure, templates and route hooks are for a given ember route definition. Its an awesome graphical representation of the route structure.

Question:

> I am in a sub route under food, say food/fruits. If I click the button
>   again I expect to be taken to the food route and then redirected to
>   options

Answer: `food` route has no URL, as it is a parent route. You will always be in a child state of this route (e.g. food.index). So when you say `transitionTo('food')` that means you are transitioning to `food.index` route.

URL `/food/fruits` - will execute `food` model hooks and `fruits` model hook.
URL `/food` - will execute `food/index` model hook and it will not execute `food` model hook.

So in your case, You can remove `this.transitionTo('food.options')` from `food` `afterModel` hook and you can introduce food.index route which has food options.

Look at modified [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a0dc6f60905afadb3e48f112fbff7123?openFiles=routes.food.index.js%2C&route=%2Ffood) which includes index route.

Comment: I guess my example is a bit too simple.  My problem comes when I am in a sub route under food, say food/fruits.  If I click the button again I expect to be taken to the food route and then redirected to options.  I thought there is a new route stack that gets created when you call transitionTo

Comment: Removed my earlier answer and updated with correct explanation. please refer [alexspeller diagonal](http://alexspeller.com/ember-diagonal/) for better understanding. Let me know if my understanding is wrong.